# Create folder at particular path

Tags: php

I'm pretty new with PHP so the question could seem easy. I have an html file with an input with these attributes:

```
<td width="30%">
<input type="text" id="prog1" name="prog1" style="width:150px">
</td>
```

I must create a new folder on my server inside another folder called `wars` that already exists. The new folder's name is stored on that input. For example, if the input's text is "home", my PHP script is gonna make a folder here: `wars/home`.

```
<?
$val = $_REQUEST['prog2'];
mkdir("/wars/".$val, 0777);
?>
```

This is my code but it's not working because inside the main folder `wars` I can't find `home`. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: try `mkdir("wars/".$val, 0777);` and then read up on relative and absolute paths

Comment: "my PHP script is gonna make a folder here: `wars/home`." --- and in the script you're creating `/wars/home`. There is a difference between `/wars` and `wars` directories

Comment: Did you examine logs after the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is a typo:

```
$val = $_REQUEST['prog2'];
```

Your form only has `<input name="prog1" ...`. However, you also have to seriously consider sanitizing your variables:

```
$val = $_REQUEST['prog1'];
// only allow alphabetical characters
if (preg_match('/^[a-z]+$/', $val)) {
    mkdir("/wars/$val", 0777);
}
```

Lastly, consider using `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST` unless you never know where the variable is going to come from.

Comment: I've used <form method="post">, so should I put $_POST instead of $_Request?

Comment: @AlbertoRossi Yes you should.

Comment: @AlbertoRossi Yes, that would be recommended; `$_REQUEST` is a combination of several parameter bags, whereas `$_POST` can only be one thing, posted parameters.

Comment: shouldn't it be mkdir("/wars/".$val,007); ?

Comment: @DK64 Both are valid options.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<?php
$val = $_POST['prog1'];
mkdir("/wars/".$val, 0777);
?>
```

notice the wrong input `prog1 !== prog2` attribute, also learn to do some simple debuging, like:

```
<?php echo '<pre>'.print_r($_POST,true).'</pre>'; ?>
```

Also enable error reporting on development.

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>
```